# Gráfico con percentiles en R

Tags: r, rstudio

Cómo podría implementarse el siguiente gráfico con ggplot2 en R:
Los datos se encuentran en el siguiente link:
https://www.bcra.gob.ar/PublicacionesEstadisticas/Relevamiento_Expectativas_de_Mercado.asp

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]